# Why java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when dynamically load a dex jar?

Tags: java, android, classloader, dynamic-loading, dexclassloader

There is a `interface IA` class in APK file.  I create a jar containing IA's `implementation MA`.  The jar has a `Global class` and `B class`. The jar is loaded dynamically with Dexclassloader from data directory.

```
interface IA {
  test();
}

class Global {
   IA instance;  //refer to  MA instance.
}

class B {
  ....
  instance.test() ; // throw NoSuchMethodError
....
}
```

But it's OK to call instance's test method through reflection.

Why?  Surely I am not familiar with some principals of Classloader or DexClassloader. Could someone give explanation for me? Thanks

Comment: you have not implemented the method. Interface just has declaration of the method. And you are not using reflection by the way.

Comment: @Batty  Instance is MA instance which implements the interface IA in apk class

Answer (score 0):

I too got a NoSuchMethod error, after doing some testing I found out that the problem was that the DEX file inside the JAR wasn't named classes.dex as it's supposed to be.
The fact that the app was able to create a new instance of your class doesn't necessarily mean that the DEX was loaded properly, I tested it with an empty JAR (i. e. removed all internal files via 7-ZIP) and was still able to instantiate my class (although I guess it would work only with a default constructor that gets zero parameters).